# Low PHP processing performance in NGINX

Tags: php, performance, apache, nginx

On my Ububtu server, I have a python script which runs 400+ threads processing some PHP files in every 30 seconds. Apache web server works fine. But when too many users hit the site, it becomes slow. So for better performance, I shifted to NGINX from apache. But now, I get poor results from those PHP files. What should I do?

Comment: How many php-cgi processes have you running as a balanced upstream? One is not enough, try 4 or 8 in an upstream.

Comment: how many Processor Core? and What is PHP-FPM pool settings?